# How to handle $http synchronous requests using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to call 3 $http requests synchronously. I mean after getting response from 1st request, 2nd request will be called. Next 3rd will be called after getting response from 2nd.

example:

```
 $http.get('FIRSTURL', param1).success(function(response){
     $http.get('SECONDURL', param2).success(function(response){
         $http.get('THIRDURL', param3).success(function(response){
            //Need to do some stuff with response
         });
     })
 });
```

Can Anyone please suggest better way to implement it using AngularJ

Comment: Why?  What is wrong with this method in your opinion?

Comment: You cannot create synchronous requests with angular JS and synchronous AJAX requests are deprecated in a majority of browsers. You can innately chain these order by using `then` on the resultant promise.

Comment: I think there must be someway similar to jQuery Deferred Object. which makes the code simpler and best practice. Another point is I want to separate out all the $http requests by creating separate method for each request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not sure how to handle it in specific AngularJS code, But still there is a work around using Javascript bind(). Please Try this.

```
myService.doSomething().then(myService.doSomething1.bind(myService)).then(myService.doSomething‌​2.bind(myService));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way to do it in order.  If you want to make it prettier, you can put each item into a function and then chain the `then` call:

```
function doSomething() {
    return $http.get('FIRSTURL', param1);
}

function doSomething1() {
    return $http.get('SECONDURL', param2);
}

function doSomething2() {
    return $http.get('THIRDURL', param3);
}
```

And then:

```
doSomething().then(doSomething1).then(doSomething2);
```

Comment: Actually I need to implement the same. But here the methods doSomething(), doSomething1() etc are part of Service.

 these functions should maintain Service context. So I need to apply the Service context. How to do that?

Comment: @Alp, as long as you have your service there, you can set it up the same way.  For example: `myService.doSomething().then(myService.doSomething1).then(myService.doSomething2)`

Comment: I will look at that in a second, but [here](http://jsbin.com/godesedano/edit?html,js,output) I've put together a jsBin demonstrating.  I'm using `$timeout` instead of `$http`, but it just returns a promise, so it's exactly the same concept

Comment: I am using ES6 . SO my service is like below :

class myService {

 constructor($http) {
  this.$http = $http;
  
 }
doSomething1() {
    return this.$http.get('SECONDURL', param2);
}
}

so if I use myService.doSomething().then(myService.doSomething1), doSomething1() will not get 'this'.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with using ecmascript 6 and Angular, so I'm not sure how exactly that works, but it should work the same as I've described.  See the jsbin I posted above to see it working with standard javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force synchronicity then you can utilize the "then" method of the promise returned from your $http invocation,
note this only synchronizes the order of your calls, it wont cause the calls to block the rest of your code.

```
$http.get('https://foo1')
.then(function(response) {
  return $http.get('https://foo2');
})
.then(function(response) {
  return $http.get('https://foo3');
})
.then(function(response) {
  return $http.get('https://foo4');
})
.catch(function(response) {
  console.error('error', response.status, response.data);
})
.finally(function() {
  console.log("finally");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 'em up like a regular promise:

```
$http.get('http://fiddle.jshell.net', param1)
    .success(function(response){
        return $http.get('http://fiddle.jshell.net', param2)
    })
    .success(function(response){
        return $http.get('http://fiddle.jshell.net', param3);
    })
    .success(function(response){
        console.log('done!');
        //Need to do some stuff with response
    });
```

Here is the example working: http://jsfiddle.net/301gt2sm/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nesting the callbacks you can use the promise feature to chain them like so:

```
$http.get('FIRSTURL', param1)
    .then(getSecond)
    .then(getThird)
    .then(function(response){
        //Need to do some stuff with response
    });
```

function getSecond(response) {
    return $http.get('SECONDURL', param2);
}

function getThird(response) {
    return $http.get('THIRDURL', param3);
}